# Erlang: convert HTTP GET param to Unicode

Tags: http, unicode, encoding, erlang, request

I am using connector on Erlang. It gets requests from Javascript like "controler?q=value". If I send a value in Unicode, the browser sends an encoded string.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/controler?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
```

How to convert this string to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a module for similar purpose some time ago: https://gist.github.com/816291
You can use it like this:

```
io:format("~ts~n",[uri:decode_uri_component("%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82")]).
тест
ok
```

Comment: It's very fine module. But how i can use it with **Req:query_param("q")** - simple bridge object from chicagoboss framework

Comment: Well, try: uri:decode_uri_component(Req:query_param("q")). But I'm not sure if chicagoboss tries to urldecode param itself

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [unicode](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/stdlib/unicode_usage.html) [module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html).